# react-router-dom (v4) unable to route to the paths mentioned in custom routes.js

Tags: react-router-dom

I am unable to route to routes.js using the react-router-dom (v4).

Here is my app.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './routes.js';

ReactDom.render(
 (
 <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <Route routes = {routes}/>
 </BrowserRouter>
 ), 
 document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

And here is the routes.js:

```
import Base from './components/Base.jsx';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.jsx';
import LoginPage from './containers/LoginPage.jsx';
import SignUpPage from './containers/SignUpPage.jsx';


const routes = {
  component: Base,
  childRoutes: [

 {
  path: '/',
  component: HomePage
},

{
  path: '/login',
  component: LoginPage
},

{
  path: '/signup',
  component: SignUpPage
}
]
};

export default routes;
```

And here is the Base.jsx:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Base = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <div className="top-bar">
      <div className="top-bar-left">
        <IndexLink to="/">React App</IndexLink>
      </div>

  <div className="top-bar-right">
    <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
    <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
  </div>

</div>

{children}

  </div>
);

Base.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Base;
```

And here is my HomePage (similarly I have SignUpPage and LoginPage):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle } from 'material-ui/Card';

const HomePage = () => (
  <Card className="container">
    <CardTitle title="React Application" subtitle="This is the home page." />
  </Card>
);

export default HomePage;
```

When I am trying to route using below method, it works fine:

```
<BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <HomePage />
</BrowserRouter>
```

I already did my research but I am not figure out whats wrong.
I do not get any error. Its just that the render method returns null.

Screenshot:
[image]

Ayy help or hint will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the idea to do this? I think you should follow the guides in the docs to get started properly: https://react-router.now.sh/

Comment: @azium it works with react-router. However its having issues with react-router-dom.

Comment: you mean react-router 3?

Comment: Yes thats right.

Comment: react-router 3 and 4 have completely different APIs that's why.

Comment: either stick with 3, or rewrite it with 4 in mind

Comment: Thanks @azium. Your comment actually made me go through the docs again. Trust me I had done it earlier but not thoroughly it seems :)   IndexLink is deprecated in RRv4. And thats the cause of null rendering. I will check each and everything going forward.